# Class class in JVM [Venner's Book]

Tags: java, jvm

I read in Venners book that When a new *Type* is loaded by the virtual machine , the virtual machine instantiates a new instance of "**Class**" and associates this instance with the new loaded type in some way ...

now my question : 
Does The VM instantiates an object of *Type* "**Class**" for the "**Class**" *Type* itself as being a class which is a type of the three reference types ?

Another Question :
When a Class B extends another class A (A is parent) Does the class B info in the method Area include All inherited features of the parent or just specific for it (B) and the Super Class pointer in it's class information is sufficient ? or it's Implementation specific ?

Thanks

Comment: The “*Type* **Class**” refers to the class [`java.lang.Class`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/lang/Class.html). And there is an instance of `Class` representing that class itself, which you can access as easy as `Class<?> classInstance = Class.class;` or even typed as `Class<Class> classInstance = Class.class;` to reflect that this reflects the type `Class`. I don’t know what you mean with “*the three reference types*”. There is only one `class Class`. The other question is about something that I consider an irrelevant implementation detail.

Comment: According to Venners A Type of the VM may be primitive (Numeric Types and returnValue) or reference(class types , interface types ,array types).. now "Class" it self is a "class type" which is consequently a "Type" .. in the VM when any Type (any of it's variants ) is loaded in the method area , an object of type class is created and associated with that type , recursively "Class" it self is a Type loaded in the Method are of the VM now does it have an object (of it's type Class) associated with it like all other objects of any "Type" have an object of "Class" specifically associated with it ?

Comment: There are also `Class` objects representing the primitive types, e.g. `int.class`, which is evaluated to the same `Class` object as stored in [`Integer.TYPE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#TYPE), which represents the primitive type `int`. And, as already said in my previous comment, there is an instance of type `Class` representing the type `Class`. Maybe your confusion stems from the phrase “any of it's variants”—what are “variants”?

Comment: i mean by "varients" the leafs (int long ..etc) of the tree representing the classification of Types ...

Comment: **as already said in my previous comment, there is an instance of type Class representing the type Class** that is exactly the point i was asking about initially ... sorry i couldn't understand that from ur first comment.. but thanks for ur help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is an instance of type `java.lang.Class` which represents the type `java.lang.Class` itself.

You get access to such a `Class` instance in two ways, by calling `getClass()` on an instance of the class or via class literal.

```
Class<?> str = "foo".getClass(); // represents type String
Class<?> cls = str.getClass(); // represents type Class
```

or

```
Class<?> str = String.class; // represents type String
Class<?> cls = Class.class; // represents type Class
```

Obviously, you can’t get the `Class` instances representing the primitive types or `void` by calling `getClass()` on an object, but there are still two ways

```
Class<?> intType = Integer.TYPE; // represents type int
Class<?> voidType = Void.TYPE; // represents type void
```

or

```
Class<?> intType = int.class; // represents type int
Class<?> voidType = void.class; // represents type void
```

---

The existence of a memory region named “method area” is already an implementation detail, so the way the data is organized within it, is even more implementation specific.